# Can't get rid of extraneous () from expression

Tags: r, list, plot, expression, substitution

I am trying to create a varying label to appear in multiple graphs, using

```
labl<-substitute(expression(tau[CODE]),list(CODE=i))[2]
```

where i is the index in the loop.

I get the following: [image]

which is fine except for the "()", that seem to come from the list function. I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I am using the exact same code used in countless other examples and can't find anyone having the same problem.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Why couldn't you just do: `substitute(tau[CODE],list(CODE=i))`?

Comment: yes, that did it! thank you, Mike!

Answer (score 3):

`substitute` already takes an expression, so no need to wrap your code in `expression`. You can simply do:

```
i = 1
substitute(tau[CODE],list(CODE=i))
#tau[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Mike’s solution is the right one. But since working with expressions in R is quite unintuitive, here’s a brief explanation why you’re getting the extraneous `()` when subsetting:

When subsetting an unevaluated expression, R essentially treats the expression as a `list`. Your original expression looks as follows:

```
〉 (expr = substitute(expression(tau[CODE]), list(CODE = 1)))
expression(tau[1])
〉 as.list(expr)
[[1]]
expression

[[2]]
tau[1]
```

Now, when calculating `expr[2]`, you’re slicing that list, but your return value is *still a list*:

```
〉 as.list(expr)[2]
[[1]]
tau[1]
```

And if you treat a list as an unevaluated expression, R *always* converts it into a function call; in fact, `as.call` is exactly the opposite of `as.list` in this context:

```
〉 as.call(list(1, 2, 3))
1(2, 3)
# same as just `expr`:
〉 as.call(as.list(expr))
expression(tau[1])
```

And hence:

```
〉 as.call(as.list(expr)[2])
tau[1]()
# same as:
〉 expr[2]
tau[1]()
```

So how to prevent this? — By using *list subsetting*, instead of *list slicing*:

```
〉 expr[[2]]
tau[1]
```

So using `[[2]]` instead of `[2]` in your code would work. But the real solution, as shown by Mike, is not to wrap your expression into `expression` in the first place.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: @MikeH. This took me extremely long to figure out myself, despite using unevaluated expressions in R routinely.

Comment: Yea, expressions in R always make my head spin. This is a really intuitive explanation though, and helped a lot with my understanding. This should be the accepted answer imo.

Answer (score -1):

I believe all you need to do is wrap your expression in the `as.character()` function like so:

```
> as.character(substitute(expression(tau[CODE]),list(CODE=i))[2])
[1] "tau[1]"
```

Comment: That’s quite interesting. But (a) it’s probably a bug in `as.character`. Compare the result with that of `deparse`, which adds the parentheses as expected. (2) It doesn’t help OP, because the string will be plotted differently.

Comment: Yep- see this now.